# Clojure: How to run my main from jar?

Tags: clojure

I have my Clojure app packed in a jar. I am launching it as:

```
java -cp lib/clojure-1.2.0.jar:my-app.jar clojure.main -e "(use 'foo.main)(-main)"
```

Is this the only way to launch my application from this jar? Specifically, I would love to see something as simple as:

```
java -cp lib/clojure-1.2.0.jar:my-app.jar clojure.main foo.main
```

Comment: Compile it: http://alexott.net/en/clojure/ClojureLein.html - w/ Leiningen, http://clojure.org/compilation - w/o it.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use

```
(ns foo.main
  (:gen-class)
```

in your main source to generate the namespace package qualified class file. Add

```
:main foo.main
:manifest {"Class-Path" "lib/clojure-1.2.0.jar"}
```

to your Leiningen project file. After "lein jar" you can startup the application using the metadata from the JAR-embedded Manifest file:

```
java -jar foo-YOURVERSION.jar
```

Comment: This worked for me. I didn't need `:manifest`. Also, I had to add `:aot [foo.main]` to get rid of the warning on `:main`. In `foo.main`, I added a `-main` function and started the system there.

Answer (score 5):

If you pack your application with leiningens uberjar task then all you need to do is run,

```
java -jar name-of-your-app.jar
```

Comment: Provided that you configured the `main` option in the `project.clj` file.

Answer (score 2):

This is possible now [1] if you can generate a correct classpath (e.g. from Leiningen):

> java -cp $(lein classpath) clojure.main -e "(do '(require
>   '[clojure.string]) (println (clojure.string/join \" \" [1 2 3])))"

Or from an uberjar:

> java -cp my_uberjar.jar clojure.main -e "(do '(require
>   '[clojure.string]) (println (clojure.string/join \" \" [1 2 3])))"

You can also do something similar from another Clojure process itself (e.g. the repl) using this library https://github.com/clojure/java.classpath

```
(clojure.java.shell/sh "java" "-cp" (clojure.string/join ":" (map #(.toString %) (clojure.java.classpath/classpath) "clojure.main" :in (pr-str '(do (require '[my.namespace]) ([my.namespace/my-main)))))
```

[1] Not sure when this was introduced